# How to create a master page?

Tags: jsp, templating

I need to create a master page in JSP to be used by other JSPs for them to have the same look and feel and menus. How can I do that in JSP?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use either

```
<%@ include file="/absoluteFragment.jsp" %>
```

or

```
<jsp:include page="relativeDynFragment.jsp" />
```

To know the difference see also http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=13517:

> The `<%@include file="abc.jsp"%>` directive acts like C `"#include"`, pulling in the text of the included file and compiling it as if it were part of the including file. The included file can be any type (including HTML or text).
>
> The `<jsp:include page="abc.jsp">` tag compiles the file as a separate JSP file, and embeds a call to it in the compiled JSP.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `<jsp:include />` tag or [JSP Templates](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javaserverpages/jsp_templates/). In case if you are familiar with [JSF](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepx.html) (JavaServer Faces technology) then use [Facelets](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqxp.html).

Comment: @sprenna - Please visit the link on post -  JSP Templates

Comment: Can anyone guide me in Facelets? I read some information about it and I would like to give it a try. But I have a question, can I use facelets template with jsp since by default the extension is .xhtml? I have bunch of jsp that need to use the template. Thanks